# Linux pip command records high cpu usage every 10 minutes

Tags: python, linux, pip

Since Google Cloud Server's CPU usage was high every 10 minutes, I used the top command to find the cause.

[Server CPU Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYSth.png)

The pip command records high cpu usage every 10 minutes.

I want to look into it in more detail. Do you have any information regarding this? Please note that the server specifications are the minimum. (2core, 1gb ram)

[Linux top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyoiV.png)

pip confirmed with top command.

```
Dec 26 16:55:01 instance-1 CRON[19027]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 26 16:58:53 instance-1 dbus-daemon[353]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.4011' (uid=0 pid=20236 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto")
Dec 26 16:58:53 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Dec 26 16:58:53 instance-1 PackageKit: daemon start
Dec 26 16:58:53 instance-1 dbus-daemon[353]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Dec 26 16:58:53 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
```

Results traced with pstree

```
systemd─┬─2*[agetty]
        ├─chronyd───chronyd
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─dhclient
        ├─dockerd─┬─docker-containe───12*[{docker-containe}]
        │         └─12*[{dockerd}]
        ├─fluent-bit───21*[{fluent-bit}]
        ├─google_guest_ag───12*[{google_guest_ag}]
        ├─google_osconfig─┬─pip
        │                 └─11*[{google_osconfig}]
        ├─haveged
        ├─nginx───2*[nginx]
        ├─otelopscol───8*[{otelopscol}]
        ├─packagekitd───3*[{packagekitd}]
        ├─polkitd───2*[{polkitd}]
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─screen───bash───screen───screen───python───3*[{python}]
        ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───sudo───su───bash───pstree
        ├─systemd───(sd-pam)
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-udevd
        └─unattended-upgr───{unattended-upgr}
```

Comment: `pip` is not a daemon or a service. Check if you don't have a scheduled (cron) task that regularly updates your environment.

Comment: @Corralien
I checked the system log and found the log below.
added the log to the content.

Calling python's pip from PackageKit?

Comment: `pip` is not  a deamon. It is one shot run by something. Check what started `pip`.  See `pstree`. Check cron. check `systemctl list-timers`. Uninstall pip, see what complains. `Calling python's pip from PackageKit?` That would be extremely odd. Also not enough logs. Check for a pattern every 10 minutes. `top` is not showing you pip arguments, see `ps aux | grep pip`. If you can't find it, get the arguments, and try to find it by using `grep something_unique -R /`

Comment: @KamilCuk
thank you I see that the `google_osconfig` process calls `pip` through `pstree`.

Answer (score 0):

Results traced with pstree

```
systemd─┬─2*[agetty]
        ├─chronyd───chronyd
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─dhclient
        ├─dockerd─┬─docker-containe───12*[{docker-containe}]
        │         └─12*[{dockerd}]
        ├─fluent-bit───21*[{fluent-bit}]
        ├─google_guest_ag───12*[{google_guest_ag}]
        ├─google_osconfig─┬─pip
        │                 └─11*[{google_osconfig}]
        ├─haveged
        ├─nginx───2*[nginx]
        ├─otelopscol───8*[{otelopscol}]
        ├─packagekitd───3*[{packagekitd}]
        ├─polkitd───2*[{polkitd}]
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─screen───bash───screen───screen───python───3*[{python}]
        ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───sudo───su───bash───pstree
        ├─systemd───(sd-pam)
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-udevd
        └─unattended-upgr───{unattended-upgr}
```

`google_osconfig` It is part of the VM Manager, this definition is in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-manager).

The following services are available as part of the VM Manager suite:

- OS inventory management: osinventory
- OS patch management: tasks
- OS configuration management: guestpolicies

Among the following parts, it is understood that pip is executed by OS patch management.

> Patch compliance overview
> After you set up the VM Manager on a VM, the following takes place on the VM:
> * The OS Config agent periodically **(about every 10 minutes)** reports `OS inventory data`.
> * The patch compliance backend periodically reads this data, cross references it with the package metadata obtained from the OS distribution and saves it.
> * The Google Cloud console then gets the patch compliance data and displays this information in the console.